# Only 1 row is inserted in foreach

Tags: php, html

UPDATE:

I have managed to correct some things. But only the first row is inserted. If the first row is not selected, nothing gets inserted.

I want only selected checkboxes from the populated table inserted into the a new table.

My table is as follows:

```
<table id="simple-table" class="table table-striped table-condensed responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th style="width:5%" class="center">
                      <label class="pos-rel">
                         <input type="checkbox" name="checked" class="ace" />
                         <span class="lbl"></span>
                     </label>
                 </th>
                 <th style="width:32%">Student Name</th>
                 <th style="width:13%">Adm. No</th>
                 <th style="width:10%" class="center">CA1 (10%)</th>
                 <th style="width:10%" class="center">CA2 (10%)</th>
                 <th style="width:10%" class="center">CA3 (10%)</th>
                 <th style="width:10%" class="center">Exam (70%)</th>
                 <th style="width:10%" class="center">Total (100%)</th>

             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <?php

            if(isset($_POST['loadStudents'])){

                $session = clean($_POST["session"]);
                $term = clean($_POST["term"]);
                $c_taught = clean($_POST["c_taught"]);
                $s_taught = clean($_POST["s_taught"]);
                $process_limit = clean($_POST["process_limit"]);
                $session_phrase = "Session";

                $sql = "SELECT `id`, `StudentID`, `StudentName` FROM tbl_students WHERE `StudentClass` = '".$c_taught."' ORDER BY `StudentName` ";

                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                            // output data of each row
                    $cnt=1;
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                       $id = $row['id']; 
                       $student_name = $row['StudentName'];
                       $student_id = $row['StudentID'];
                       ?>
                       <tr>
                           <td class="center">
                              <label class="pos-rel">
                                 <input type="checkbox" class="ace" name="checked[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" />
                                 <span class="lbl"></span>
                             </label>
                         </td>
                         <td><?php echo $student_name; ?><input type="hidden" name="student_name[]" value="<?php echo $row['StudentName']; ?>"/></td>
                         <td><?php echo $student_id; ?><input type="hidden" name="student_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['StudentID']; ?>"/></td>
                         <td class="center"><?php echo '<input type="text" maxlength="2" size="6" name="CA1[]" autofocus>'; ?></td>
                         <td class="center"><?php echo '<input type="text" maxlength="2" size="6" name="CA2[]">'; ?></td>
                         <td class="center"><?php echo '<input type="text" maxlength="2" size="6" name="CA3[]">'; ?></td>
                         <td class="center"><?php echo '<input type="text" maxlength="2" size="6" name="Exam[]">'; ?></td>
                         <td class="center"><?php echo '<input type="text" maxlength="2" size="6" name="Total[]">'; ?></td>                
                     </tr>
                     <?php $cnt=$cnt+1;}}
                     else {
                        $msg = "<span class='red'><h4> No data available for your selection. </h4></span>";  
                    }
                }

                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My inset script is as follows: (On the same page with the form)

```
<?php
$enroll_sql = "";
if(isset($_POST['add_assessment'])) {
if(empty($_POST['checked'])){
    echo '<script>alertify.alert("No Student is selected.",function(e){if(e){document.location.href = "cass_entry.php";}}).set("labels", {ok:"OK!"}).set("defaultFocus", "ok").set("title", "Assessment")
    </script>';
    exit();

}

foreach($_POST['checked'] as $id=>$value) {
    $session = $_POST['session'];
    $term = $_POST['term'];
    $c_taught = $_POST['c_taught'];
    $s_taught = $_POST['s_taught'];
    $student_id = $_POST['student_id'][$id];
    $student_name = $_POST['student_name'][$id];
    $ca_1 = $_POST['CA1'][$id];
    $ca_2 = $_POST['CA2'][$id];
    $ca_3 = $_POST['CA3'][$id];
    $exam = $_POST['Exam'][$id];
    $total = $_POST['Total'][$id];

    $enroll_sql .= '
    INSERT INTO tbl_subjects_enrollment (`Session`,`Term`,`Student_Class`,`Subject_Name`,`Student_ID`,`Student_Name`,`CA_1`,`CA_2`,`CA_3`,`Exam`,`Total`) 
    VALUES("'.$session.'", "'.$term.'", "'.$c_taught.'", "'.$s_taught.'", "'.$student_id.'", "'.$student_name.'", "'.$ca_1.'", "'.$ca_2.'", "'.$ca_3.'", "'.$exam.'", "'.$total.'")';

    echo $enroll_sql;

    if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $enroll_sql)) {
        $success_msg = '<div class="alert alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
        <h4><i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"> Success</i></h4>
        <p>Assessment scores were successfully saved.</p></div>';

    } else {
        echo "Error saving Assessment: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: When developing, and you run into unwanted results, its good habit to always stick this at the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? It should be fairly simple to find out why the code does not do what it should

Comment: @IncredibleHat, thanks. @Nico, when I used @IncredibleHat's ERROR REPORT, I got this: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO tbl_subjects_enrollment (Session,Term,Student_Class,Subject_Name,Stu' at line 3' in C:\...\cass_entry.php on line 44`

Answer (score 0):

Watch, your first checkbox isn't named as an array and has no value :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checked" class="ace" />
```

It may result in a simple var $_POST['checked'] which isn't an array (nor a string since it hasn't value) and won't be passed in your foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Look :

```
foreach($_POST['checked'] as $id=>$value) {

$enroll_sql .= '
INSERT INTO tbl_subjects_enrollment (`Session`,`Term`,`Student_Class`,`Subject_Name`,`Student_ID`,`Student_Name`,`CA_1`,`CA_2`,`CA_3`,`Exam`,`Total`) 
VALUES("'.$session.'", "'.$term.'", "'.$c_taught.'", "'.$s_taught.'", "'.$student_id.'", "'.$student_name.'", "'.$ca_1.'", "'.$ca_2.'", "'.$ca_3.'", "'.$exam.'", "'.$total.'")';

echo $enroll_sql;

if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $enroll_sql)) {
    $success_msg = '<div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i>
    </button>
    <h4><i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"> Success</i></h4>
    <p>Assessment scores were successfully saved.</p></div>';

} else {
    echo "Error saving Assessment: " . $conn->error;
}
}
```

You concatenate your SQL query each time => and execute it each time adding the previous queries.
If you didn't forget your semi-colon it would have ended inserting too many time the same line (and actually that's why only the first Insert is working).

The problem here is the concatenation of the query AND the missing semi-colon of your query.

In order to make your code work fine, you juste have to not concatenate your query :
`$enroll_sql = '...'; // = not .=`
OR
let it concatenated BUT execute the query **OUTSIDE** your foreach loop (and adding a semi-colon at the end of the SQL query :
`, "'.$total.'");'; // ; at the end of the query`

Answer (score 0):

I wanna thank all contributors especially @WizardNx.

I eventually solved it (**Necessity is the mother of creativity**):

It appears the checkbox was not assigning unique `id` to each row. In fact, if I check `row_3` and fill all the inputs, it will insert for `row_1` but assign `row_3 id`.

Here is what I did:

```
<tr>
   <td class="center">
       <label class="pos-rel">
          <input type="checkbox" class="ace" name="studentSelect[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['StudentID']; ?>" />
            <span class="lbl"></span>
       </label>
  </td>
  <td><?php echo $row['StudentName']; ?><input type="hidden" name="student_name[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['StudentName']; ?>"/></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['StudentID']; ?></td>
  <td class="center"><input type="text" maxlength="2" size="6" name="CA1[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" autofocus></td>
  <td class="center"><input type="text" maxlength="2" size="6" name="CA2[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]"></td>
  <td class="center"><input type="text" maxlength="2" size="6" name="CA3[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]"></td>
  <td class="center"><input type="text" maxlength="2" size="6" name="Exam[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]"></td>
  <td class="center"><input type="text" maxlength="2" size="6" name="Total[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]"></td>
</tr>
```

I added `id` to each input on each row.